# Android change seekbar color

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android, android-seekbar, android-slider

I have this `SeekBar` in my app:

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/volume_seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:theme="@style/Volume_Seekbar" />
```

And this is the style file:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/toolbar_background</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBarStyle">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="Volume_Seekbar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/app_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/toolbar_background</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/app_blue</item>
</style>
```

I want to use the style to change the color of the `SeekBar` but it keeps taking the color definition from the `AppTheme` style. Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: On which device you have tested & API level?

Comment: @Raj Using Android 9(Samsung 8) , API level - 28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a **`SeekBar`** you can use:

```
   <SeekBar
        android:theme="@style/MySeekBar"
        />
```

with:

```
<style name="MySeekBar">
    <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">@color/....</item>
    <item name="android:progressTint">@color/...</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

[image]
[image]

Now you can also use the new **`Slider`** components provided by the Material Components Library:

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
       android:valueFrom="0"
       android:valueTo="300"
       android:value="200"
       android:theme="@style/slider_red"
       />
```

You can override the default color using something like:

```
  <style name="slider_red">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#......</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

**Note:** `Slider` requires the version `1.2.0` of the Material Components.